# CMake Build a target as part of project and independently

Tags: c++, cmake

I am attempting to write CMakeLists.txt for a platform. The platform has multiple projects which share some libraries and have their own executables. I wish to be able to build each project as a whole, as well as individual executables from within the project.

out-of-source root build works fine:

```
mkdir root-build && cd root-build && cmake ../root
```

out-of-source executable build does not work:

```
mkdir ui-build && cd ui-build && cmake ../root/project1/ui
```

My current directory structure is as follows:

```
root/
+-- CMakeListst.txt
+-- lib/
    +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- sharedLib1/
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- sharedLIb2/
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- project1/
    +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- ui/
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- executable1/
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- shared/
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- project2/
    +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- executable/
        +-- CMakeLists.txt
```

My current project structure builds all targets and libraries as part of the project great, but I can't figure out how to build an executable in isolation.

The main cmake file for a project is `root/project*/CMakeLists.txt`. This file `INCLUDES` `root/CMakeLists.txt`, which does some setup common to all projects (e.g setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and `find_package` for third-party libraries). The project cmake file also calls `add_subdirectory` for each of it's executables and `add_subdirectory(../lib libs)`.

This allows executables to link against any of the targets defined in the `root/lib` subdirectory. If I then try to build the executable independently of the project, CMake will not be able to find the target the executable needs to link against. Is there an elegant solution / pattern that would allow this? One way I thought of was to just `add_subdirectory(../../ root)` from the ui/CMakeLists.txt, with something resembling header guards to prevent an infinite add_subdirectory loop.

Comment: Please provide the error logs of both commands and the contains of the `root/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: You can't `add_subdirectory` outside of the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` or you need to pass a second argument to add_subdirectory i.e. the build_dir

Comment: It does have a second argument, "root" is not part of the path

Answer (score 0):

Use `make executable1` (for example) to build individual targets.